# Preview using an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to preview a website using a iframe.

i.e, the size of the iframe should be should be as of the suggested videos o youtube.

Thanks..

Comment: Huh?! What exactly do you want to accomplish here?

Comment: I'm going to upvote this to at least even things out.  This question is useful - I can't understand why someone would just downvote it.

Comment: Thanks for understanding the importance..

Comment: @code4life: because it's unclear what is asked and why is it needed.

Comment: @MaxVT, lack of information by the OP is not a valid reason to downvote - lack of relevance is.  And until we *get* more information, the question can't be non-relevant (innocent unless proven guilty, etc. etc.)  If we used downvotes to punish everything that peeves us, what kind of a site would stackoverflow become?  Which is why I upvoted to cancel your downvote...  :)

Comment: @code4life: this is becoming a meta discussion. I do not consider this a good question because it's neither "detailed and specific" nor "written clearly and simply" (from the FAQ). It's my personal opinion and the reason for my downvote. You think differently and so the votes even out. I'd say the system works pretty well, then? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to zoom IFRAME content only without using a frame set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203064/how-to-zoom-iframe-content-only-without-using-a-frame-set)

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com" style="width:150px; height:150px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As told in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203064/how-to-zoom-iframe-content-only-without-using-a-frame-set) already.

You can use [AnythingZoomer](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/) to change insides of div.

### Example

Create frame.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#webpage").load("<?=$_GET['url']?>");
    })
</script>
<div id="webpage" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

And then load it where you need it with:

```
<iframe scr="frame.php?url=http://www.google.com" height="300" widht="300">
```

And set zoom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#webpage").anythingZoomer({
       expansionSize: 30,
       speedMultiplier: 1.4
    });
</script>
```