# How to zoom IFRAME content only without using a frame set?

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe

I need to zoom frame content only. Here in my web page I used `zoom: 0.75; height: 520px; width: 800px;`.  If I increase the zoom value it means that the frame size will be increased.

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
 <STYLE>

#frame { width: 800px; height: 520px; border: 1px solid black; }
#frame { zoom: 0.75; -moz-transform: scale(0.75); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; }
</STYLE>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>

  <IFRAME id="frame" src="http://www.google.com"></IFRAME> 

  </BODY>

</HTML>
```

In the above sample HTML page I want to zoom the content of the IFRAME without changing the size of that IFRAME.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I scale the content of an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 15):

I have used a script in my facebook and it's working in IE and Firefox

```
<style type="text/css">
#iframe {
    zoom: 0.15;
    -moz-transform:scale(0.75);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.75);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
</style>

<iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/"  height="700" width="550">Wikipedia Encyclopedia</iframe>
```

Comment: That's great - but **do not use** `zoom` **and** one of the vendor specific properties. Eg: if you use Chrome, your `iframe` gets zoomed AND transformed - what leads to a double-zooming.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, does it? The OP clearly wants to scale the **contents** of the iframe, **not** the iframe itself.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure this works with linked documents, but with locally hosted content the following works:

```
<IFRAME id="frame" src="local.pdf#zoom=100"></IFRAME>
```

Answer (score 3):

For this you might need to use javascript.

There is a zoom plugin for jQuery here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/

You could change the iframes src to a local web page (eg. frame.htm), place a div in the frame and use the jquery load() function to load the content into the frame:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#loadGoogle").load("pageToLoad.html", function(){ 
             //loaded
          });
    })
</script>
<div id="loadGoogle" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

Then use the jquery zoom plugin inside the frame to zoom the content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#loadGoogle").anythingZoomer({

       expansionSize: 30,
       speedMultiplier: 1.4

    });
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is, you're telling the iframe to zoom, not the content of the iframe. By using the CSS "#frame { zoom: 0.75..." you won't get the desired result.

Comment: Hello. This does'nt work if the source is a PDF file, even if it is referenced on another HTML.

Answer (score 0):

For an updated answer this is a great guide. Cheers

http://www.collaboration133.com/how-to-scale-iframe-content-in-ie-chrome-firefox-and-safari/2717/

Comment: Avast says, the page is infected with JS:Iframe-ELE [Trj]