# Re-style widget after everything loaded

Tags: css, widget

I have a widget that loads from an external site. The widget width is larger than my site and I want to resize it. But whatever I've tried nothing changes. I try to write CSS rules with "!important", I have used jQuery to resize after document loaded but it does not work.

How can i overwrite the widget's CSS rules. Why nothing is working?

Comment: is it loaded in an iframe maybe?

Comment: If you loads it within an iframe, i'm not sure you can overwrite something, unless the zoom within the iframe : [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203064/how-to-zoom-iframe-content-only-without-using-a-frame-set)

Comment: Yes unfortunately it is iframe.

Answer (score 0):

By using the Chrome DevTools you may view the Computed styles on the right as depicted in the screenshot.

[image]

Find the property that you are working on and there should be a link to the CSS file that defines that property.

If the element appears within an iframe, use the following loop to wait until the iframe has loaded.

`while ( $( "iframe" ) == false ) { ; }`

As soon as the iframe has loaded, the `while` loop will exit and then you may apply your css using jQuery.

`$("#myiFrameElement").css("background-color", "yellow");`

Comment: The widget is in iframe tags.