# How to hide part of the content of an iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to make an iframe of this https://rustypipe.deepraven.co/video/8ci2hj7CSHI/ (which is a random youtube video). However I do not want for the search bar or the rustypipe logo to be seen. I want the iframe to be only focused on the video.

How do I achieve this with html and css?

This is what I mean:

I do not want this.
[image: video with menu and search bar]

I want this.

[image: video only]

UPDATE: I need it to be an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need the `iframe`, you could embed only the video (copy the `<video>` tag from the website).
Most Browsers let you right click on the DOM Node in the inspector (press `F12` to get there) and copy the HTML.

Inside the `<video>` tag, there are links to the video source, so you don't have to download the video.

If you do need the `iframe`, you will probably have to render the whole content (not a big deal for your case) and zoom into the part, that you want to see.

Here is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203064/how-to-zoom-iframe-content-only-without-using-a-frame-set) about that. The bottom comment also mentions this [blog post](https://collaboration133.com/how-to-scale-iframe-content-in-ie-chrome-firefox-and-safari/2717/).

Comment: I'm aware of the video tag but for my specific situation I really need it to be an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<p>` tag right above the `<a>` tag. Set the `background` to white, `position` absolute, and give it an appropriate `width` and `height` and there ya have it:

[image]

After, you can also use after css `transform` properties like `scale` to get to the size you want. Let me know if you have any questions!

---

Here is a screenshot of the additional

tag in the HTML and the classes set on it

[image]

Let me know if that makes sense. We're basically just taking a white strip and putting it over the part we don't want.

Don't use my exact measurements, i'm sure you will find the perfect ones for yours :)

Comment: could you give me an example. I'm not sure where in the iframe i should have a p tag or an a tag? Do I wrap the iframe with a p tag?

Comment: Sure! I guess i will add another answer because it wont let me post a photo to a comment. --- nevermind will expand on my above answer